# How to run older then api 29 android emulator on M1 Mac (api 24, 25 builds don't work)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo, apple-m1

Desperately I need to test certain android versions and have M1 mac for some time. New versions of emulator runs super fast and I didn't realized there are any issues but now I tried build api 25 and api 24 that are also Arm64v8a but they just open window and doesn't start up at all.
I actually needed to test Android 8 for some bug in one app but don't know how to do it now, I can see just api 24 and api 25 arm64 emulators that is android 7 and 7.1 but even those don't start at all.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but how about trying genymotion to test your app, if the standard does not work

Comment: @Yura you are using it on M1 arm processor ?  I didn't checked it quite some time so don't know have to look at it.. I was using for some years back in the days when emulator was slow.. But thanks honestly I totaly forgot it exists...

Comment: Looks like VirtualBox doesn't run on M1  at all. So you probably just said it while using intel computer.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a related bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207732539

Feel free to star the issue !